# What to do with out of scope wildlife questions

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I recently suggested that the question [How to help a wild baby parrot who cannot fly?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/73511/how-to-help-a-wild-baby-parrot-who-cannot-fly) be posted here, as the answer needed was out of scope at pets.se.  It was closed here, as out of scope as well.

After some research it seems like **The Great Outdoors** is a suitable home for these types of question.

See Related [Questions about wildlife support on The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/questions-about-wildlife-support-on-the-great-outdoors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure which site is the most appropriate for these questions. This question is off topic here because it does not focus on a biological fact or analytical method. It would also be off-topic on the same grounds as personal health questions.

It seems that [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) considers questions like these as on-topic.

So, unless there is a new stackexchange dedicated to wildlife, questions like these can be migrated there.

Comment: I think that's fine, but I'd also say that "How to help a wild baby parrot who cannot fly?" questions *are* basically personal medical questions. No one but an expert who is familiar with the situation can give anything more than cursory advice. Outdoors might be accepting them, but I don't know if that's entirely appropriate. Their community is not a veterinary community.